# Menu with unusual rounded corners

Tags: css, menu

how would style this menu? I don't know how to style these rounded corners on hover.

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: Make the active the inactive? it just looks like an inverted typical bubble-style menu.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @BradChristie, as far as I understand, the problem is to make rounded the corners _of the items around the hovered one_, not just swap the normal and hovered state styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/HZf5g/2/)?

```
.menu-item {
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    background: #444;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    border-left: 7px solid #444; /* hide the rounded corners of the previous link */
    margin-left: -7px;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    background: transparent; /* show the gradient background of the container */
    border-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.menu-item:first-child, .menu-item:hover + .menu-item {
    border-radius: 6px; /* the 1st link and the link next to hovered
                           have left rounded corners */
    border-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: And how would you style if those links were in list?
There is a problem with this part .menu-item:hover + .menu-item

Comment: But there is no problem with `.menu-item:hover + menu-item a` in that case: http://jsfiddle.net/HZf5g/5/ :)

Comment: Thank you! One last question. On first item there aren't rounded corners on the left side (right side on last item). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes, it can be done, for example, with pseudo-elements of the list element: http://jsfiddle.net/HZf5g/6/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reverse what you would normally do: make active links the same background colour as the container and without border radius, and inactive with border radius and a different background colour.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li class='active'>Link 2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {background:grey;}
li {background:black; border-radius:5px;}
li.active {background:grey; border-radius:0;}
```

If you want the active link to have a gradient like in the image, give the containing div a gradient as a background and make the active link's background transparent:

```
li.active {background:transparent;}
```